# Python - Spin up multiple ChromeDriver instances

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to simultaneously spin up multiple ChromeDriver instances without calling them each explicitly, i.e.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver3 = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver4 = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
```

A for loop launches one and then only launches another one if the current one is closed..

Comment: A for loop shouldn't make any difference at all. Show your loop code. I bet that e.g. `drivers = [webdriver.Chrome() for i in range(3)]` will open three browsers.